# Getting NetworkOnMainThreadException with RxKotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-kotlin

I'm trying to make a network request using RxKotlin, but keep getting a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` I'm subscribing on the main thread, so I'm not sure why it's not taking it off of the UI thread.

Here is where I subscribe to the Observable

```
weatherInteractor.getWeather(lat, lng)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                        {response ->
                            try {
                                val jsonData = response.body().string()
                                val currentWeather = getCurrentWeatherData(jsonData)
                                view!!.displayCurrentWeather(currentWeather)
                            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                                Log.d("Present JSON Exception", e.message)
                            } catch (e: IOException) {
                                Log.d("Present IO Exception", e.message)
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            error ->
                            error.printStackTrace()
                        }
                )
    }
```

Here is where I create my Observable

```
fun getWeather(lat: Double, lng: Double): Observable<Response> {
        val URL = ""
        val client = OkHttpClient()
        val request = Request.Builder()
                .url(URL)
                .build()

        return Observable.create { em ->
            try {
                val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
                em.onNext(response)
                em.onComplete()
            } catch (err: IOException) {
                err.printStackTrace()
                em.onError(err)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please comment if you downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you confuse `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` methods.

`subscribeOn` specifies the scheduler observable will be created on and will operate on. (You specify it once, position doesn't matter).

`observeOn` changes the scheduler *for every action you type after it*.
You can use it multiple times and each set of actions will be executed on specified scheduler.

Here is an example:

```
Observable
            .just("test")
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map(s -> { //this and all Observable code is executed on Schedulers.io()

                return s;
            })
            .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .map(s -> { // executed on Schedulers.computation()

                return s;
            })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(s -> { // executed on Android main thread

            }, throwable -> {

            });
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm seeing the difference.

Comment: from your code: `weatherInteractor.getWeather(lat, lng)
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`

You make request on `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` and code in `.subscribe()` (The `Observer`) runs on `Schedulers.io()`

Comment: I see. I switched both of them, `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`, and `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`, but it gives the same error

Comment: Just tested the following code [see the gist](https://gist.github.com/amaksoft/9cdd14caffc1fd11f5de9b4e2d48cbf2)
Worked exactly as intended (given android.permission.INTERNET in AndroidManifest.xml)

Comment: I can upload the whole test project if needed

Comment: could you please? At this point I think it may be something in my dependencies or how I set it up.

Comment: Here you go: [example project](https://github.com/amaksoft/stackexchange-46459906)

Comment: In the end, updating to okhttp3 was I think what did it.